# How to make a Web App that works with beacons?

Tags: web, web-applications, react-native, ibeacon, beacon

I know you can work with beacons with a iOS app or Android app.
But you can work with a web app to?
(A website recognize a beacon and do something)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **the general answer is no.**  You need native components to detect Bluetooth beacons on both Android and iOS.  The web browsers on both operating systems have no hooks to detect beacons via JavaScript or HTML.

Chrome OS does have Bluetooth bindings in its Chrome browser, which may allow you to build a web app on Chrome OS that does this.  But this would really be a Chrome App not a general purpose web app.

The Chrome browser for iOS and Android also detects Eddystone-URL beacons, but it will not pass the detection info to a web app. Detections are sent to the user as a notification and tapping on that notification simply brings up a configured URL in the Chrome web browser.  This does not allow any dynamic web app behavior based on beacon detections.